# How to simplify (one lining) a recursive function that's calling a function on an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am wondering if there's something I misunderstood here.
The code is:

```
function countdown(n){
  if(n < 1) return [];
  let result = countdown(n - 1);
  result.unshift(n);
  return result;
}
```

I'm wondering why it can't be written like this:

```
function countdown(n){
  if(n < 1) return [];
  return countdown(n - 1).unshift(n);
}
```

This returns an error:

```
TypeError: countdown(...).unshift is not a function
```

Aren't both of them the same thing?

Comment: [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) returns the new length of the array, not the array itself. You return this number (instead of the array) then try to call `unshift` on it, which is a non-existent function for Numbers.

Comment: Try surrounding the countdown() function in parenthesis: (countdown(n - 1)).unshift(n). Might work like that.

Comment: @Alex_89 this will still return the new length as a number, so the same error will occur

Comment: You can use the spread syntax to make it more concise if you wish `return [n, ...countdown(n - 1)];`

Comment: you are trying to call unshift method from function prototype . But function does not have that method . unshift method is with Array prototype so either convert it to array or add this function in function prototype.

Comment: @RoliAgrawal: No, the first time that's called, it's on `[]`, not on the function.  And the goal would be, if not for the problems described in other comments, that it would be called on the array returned by the recursive call.

Comment: @byxor Thanks a lot, you've made my day. I guess after this, i need to check the return of a function properly 

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes, the [ ] was the problem i was confused of. But now I know that the problem lies on my misunderstanding on .unshift().